# Prophet Isaiah's visit to Ahaz in Isaiah 7, was it before or after what happened in 2 Chronicles 28- 5:15?

Tags: history, nevua-prophecy, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

**According to [2 Chronicles 28](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.28.5-15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en),**

Aram-Damascus, under Rezin, and Israel, under Pekah, attempted to depose Ahaz through an invasion. Judah was being defeated and, according to 2 Chronicles 28, lost 120,000 troops in just one day. Many significant officials were killed, including the king's son Maaseiah. Many others were taken away as slaves.

**According to [Isaiah 7](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.7?lang=bi)**

Isaiah tells King Ahaz that the invasion will be unsuccessful and tells him to ask God for a sign. Ahaz refuses, claiming he does not want to test God. Isaiah then announces that God himself will choose the sign, etc.

The question:

Prophet Isaiah's visit to Ahaz in Isaiah 7, was it before or after what happened in 2 Chronicles 28- 5:15?

If the visit and prophecy of Emanuel, was before the horrible things that happened in 2 Chronicles 28- 5:15, then how could the prophecy of Emanuel had been a promise of salvation, protection to the house of David, from the danger of the impending invasion of Aram and Ephraim?

Comment: "_Isaiah tells King Ahaz that the invasion will be unsuccessful_ ..." (1) Did Isaiah tell King Ahaz that the invasion wouldn't happen? (2) [Isaiah 7:5-6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.5-6?lang=bi&lang2=en) says: "_Because the Arameans—with Ephraim and the son of Remaliah—have plotted against you, saying, ‘We will march against Judah and invade and conquer it, and we will set up as king in it the son of Tabeel,’_" Did they conquer Judah? Did they set the son of Tabeel as king there? They, and the Assyrians, certainly wreaked havoc in Judah, but was the invasion successful?

Comment: "... _[H]ow could the prophecy of Emanuel had been a promise of salvation, protection to the house of David, from the danger of the impending invasion of Aram and Ephraim_"? What protection to the house of David was prophesied? That non of Ahaz's sons will die in the invasion?? Ahaz was succeeded by his son Hezekiah ([2 Chronicles 28:27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.28.27?lang=bi&lang2=en)).

Comment: When was the prophecy of Emanuel supposed to be fulfilled? [Isaiah 7:14,16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.14-16?lang=bi&lang2=en) says: "_Look, the young woman **is with child** and about to give birth to a son_ ... _For before the **lad knows to** reject the bad and choose the good_ ...". That would suggests that these prophesied events are some time after the impending invasion.

Comment: thank you Tamir for the comments.

Comment: some of bible commentaries ,put this visit after what happened in 2 Chronicles 28. !

Comment: according to Pulpit Commentary : In Kings the alliance between Rezin and Pekah is distinctly declared, as also the fact that they conjointly besieged Jerusalem (2 Kings 16:5). From Chronicles we learn that, before the siege, Ahaz was twice defeated with great loss, once by the Syrians (2 Chronicles 28:5), and once by the Israelites (2 Chronicles 28:6). He was probably, therefore, reduced to great straits at the time when Isaiah interview with him, and communicate to him a comforting message from Jehovah. .......

Comment: I wasn't arguing for Isaiah's visit to Ahaz happening before what happened in 2 Chronicles 28:5-15, nor was I arguing against it having happened later. I was just commenting that you aren't sufficiently supporting your argument against the visit having happened earlier than what happened in 2 Chronicles 28:5-15, in terms of what was actually promised, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Rabbi Yigal Ariel](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%92%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C) in his book on Yesha'ayhu, "Hamevaser", pt. 1, pg. 130-131, first Aram and Israel attacked Judah as described in Chronicles 2:28 and then, subsequently, Yesha'ayhu came to speak with Achaz to try to convince him not to beg for help from the Assyrians.

Comment: thanx Harel , the words of  Rabbi Yigal Ariel makes much sense.. most bible commentaries agree with him,though some disagree... that is why I was confused. now I'm convinced that the visit came after the attack ..the prophet's advice was right ,and history proved it,

Comment: I also heard that "_Yesha'ayhu came to speak with Achaz to try to convince him not to beg for help from the Assyrians_". I didn't see it in the words of Yesha'ayhu (beyond the promise that Aram and Israel's conquest won't last long, as Assyria will conquer both kingdoms in the near future anyway). From where does R. Yigal Ariel conclude that was Yesha'ayhu's intent?

Comment: If "_Aram and Israel attacked Judah_" before "_Yesha'ayhu came to speak with Achaz_", how does R. Yigal Ariel understand the "נחה ארם על אפרים" report that the House of David received ([Isaiah 7:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.2?lang=bi&lang2=en))? I would have thought that means the visit happened when they were still getting together, before they attacked Judah.

Comment: @Tamir Evan . with regard to (Isaiah 7:2) according to Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible : "and the weakness of the king and people of Judah, who were like to trees shaken by the wind; and also the fear they were possessed with, partly through consciousness of guilt, and partly through distrust of divine power and Providence; and also on account of what they had suffered already from these powerful enemies, when they attacked them singly; and therefore might much more dread them, as they were combined together against them; see 2 Chronicles 28:5."

Comment: @caprireds I wasn't asking how Isaiah 7:2 could fit with the position that Isaiah's visit to Ahaz in Isaiah 7, happened after the events described in 2 Chronicles 28:5-15. For that, I could have gone with [Malbim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbim)'s [commentary to Isaiah 7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Malbim_on_Isaiah.7.1.1-2.1) (sorry, no online English translation), rather than [John Gill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Gill_(theologian))'s expositions. I was asking for R. Yigal Ariel's explanation, as his view is brought in the answer.